# How can I see how many up/down votes I've cast on a given day?

Tags: support, voting

I'm trying to figure out how many more votes I can cast today, and to do that I need to know how any votes I've already cast today. I've already checked the Help Center for information, but no luck. How can I view the number of votes I've cast on any given day?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Click here @@>>> https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=topactivity

Scroll down to the bottom and see this:

> [image]

The three columns "month", "week" and "day" may not appear if you haven't voted in that period.

Comment: Does this apply for only up/down votes or *any* type of vote?

Comment: @publicstaticvoidmain Up/down only.

Comment: @publicstaticvoidmain you can see how many close/reopen/delete/undelete votes are left by attempting to perform the action (you don’t have to actually go through with it). Same for flags.